# Sorting Entries field results by category

Tags: categories, entries-field

I have an entries field 'physicians'. I want to output the selections from that field and sort them by category (also named 'physicians') - with the category heading above each category group.

I can't figure out if I should just output the category list and filter the result by the field or if I should output the entries field and then sort them by category. I'm trying the latter right now but not sure of how to get the categories to work.

```
{% set phyGroup = craft.categories.group('physicians') %}
{% set phyList = craft.entries.relatedTo('physicians').order('lastName asc') %}

{% for physicians in phyGroup %}
   <h3>{{ category }}</h3>
   {% for entry in phyList %}
      {{ entry.lastName }} ...
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Am I right in assuming that you have a Categories field added to the field layout of the entries that you pick with your `physicians` Entries field? What’s the handle of that field?

Comment: Yes, on the entries that I pick from there is a categories field named 'specialityCat'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s not totally clear from your question where you’re building the relation to the categories,
but I have a feeling that this is the solution you’re looking for.

```
{% set groupParam = '{ object.categoriesFieldHandle.first() ? object.categoriesFieldHandle.first().title : "No categories" }' %}
{% for groupTitle, entriesInGroup in entry.entriesFieldHandle|group(groupParam) %}
    {{ groupTitle }}

    {% for entry in entriesInGroup %}
        {{ entry.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am trying to show the entries selected in the entries field but sort them in category groups. The entries I'm pulling from have a category field called 'specialityCat'. Would I need to use this in conjunction with the 2 'set' parameters I have above? Not getting this to work yet but I have this: 

`{% for group, entriesInGroup in entry.physicians|group('specialityCat') %}
    {{ group.title }}

    {% for entry in entriesInGroup %}
        <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}`

Comment: @David I updated the code example, should work now.